# How to use Google Platform API Key restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, geolocation, amazon-cloudfront

we want to use API Keys of Google Platform for Geolocate and Maps service

But i don't understand how to restrict the API

If i restrict like this (sub.example.com/*) wuth HTTP referrer, when I hit geolocation/maps service, it return "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API."

I've read than we can use IP address instead of using HTTP referrer, but my site come from an S3 bucket on AWS, which has his address redirect by Cloudfront (for HTTPS) and Route53, so i don't really know how can i find IP address of my website.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: IP address isn't the solution. Are you sure of the host presented to MAPS Api when your S3 website perform its query?

Comment: The host I use to restrict Maps API is the Route 53 address. My S3 bucket give me an HTTP address, and i use Cloudfront and Route 53 to have a custom domain in HTTPS.
Do you think I need to use the S3 URL ?

Comment: I think there is URL mismatch. That's why I ask to help you but I never use this configuration to be sure of my answer... Maybe route the call to a dummy service which only print request header. And you could see the host presented by it.